# Python - taking input as i as part of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I have a simple program but the input question part is not working as it should. I simply want the "i" in the for loop, as part of the input question to the user, to print 0,1,2,3 etc.

instead of gives an error.

Code below

```
def multapp():
  
  score=0
  lives=3
  
  for i in range(4):
    answer1=input("2 x",i)
    if answer1=="2":
      print("well done child")
      score=score+1
    else:
      print("No")
      lives=lives-1
   
  print("lives:",lives)
  print("score:",score)

multapp()
```

Comment: What's the full traceback for your error?

Comment: `answer=input(f"2 x {i}")`. And you don't to hard-code the correct answer `if answer == f"{2 * i}":`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"2 x"` from the input function:

```
def multapp():  
    score=0
    lives=3

    for i in range(4):
       answer1=input(i)
       if answer1=="2":
       print("well done child")
       score=score+1
       else:
           print("No")
           lives=lives-1

print("lives:",lives)
print("score:",score)

multapp()
```